# offsetX and offsetWidth

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have a issue in determining the value of a div.

When I resize the window, the offsetX property of a div changes accordingly. Say for example on a maximised window, the offsetX starts from 0 to 100 . But when I resize the window then the offsetX starts from 0 to 70,50, etc based on the window width I have resized.

But the offsetWidth of the div remains the same irrespective of window size. Is there any property in css/js for a div, which changes the offsetWidth similar to the way offsetX does?

Comment: jQuery's outerWidth can do that i think